# unmarshal using jaxb having inner tag

Tags: java, ajax

I want to unmarshal my below xml file using JAXB.

```
     <School>
      <Student>
      <Name> My xyz<Name>
      <Hobbies> Playing Cricket <sup>+</sup> Watching TV</Hobbies> 
      </Student>
    </School>
```

In Above example , There is one school with student which having hobbies.
  Whenever i unmarshal above xml using (@XmlPath) i got only "Watching TV" but not "Playing Cricket".

I have tried to unmarshal using "DomHandler" also but not success.

Thanks.

Comment: *In Above example*  -- I see no example

Comment: I have just added example.

Comment: Your xml is not a valid one, the `Hobbies` tag is not closed, and it seems you have that `sup` tag that is not closed either.

Comment: Sorry , Updated. Closed Hobbies and sup

Comment: Your XML is not valid. < and > must be encoded as &lt; and &gt;

Answer (score 0):

I think your XML should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <School>
        <Student>
            <Name>My xyz</Name>
            <Hobbies>
                <Name>Playing Cricket</Name>
                <Hobby>
                </Hobby>
                <Name>Playing Cricket</Name>
            </Hobbies>
        </Student>
        <!-- OTHER STUDENTS FOLLOW-->
    </School>
```

and then the correspondant java object structure would be something like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlRootElement(name = "School")
        class School {
            @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Student")
            Student student;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        class Hobby {
            @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Name")
            String name;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        class Student {
            @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Name")
            String name;
            @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Hobbies")
            List<Hobby> hobbies;
        }
```

I took off the getters and the setters for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but what i want to parse that whenever html tag in text (Playing Cricket <sup>+</sup> Watching TV) then JAXB will set only "Watching TV" text into Hobbies variable.

Comment: @JITENPATEL to do so you have to put that in a CDATA section